# Finding an element using src or href code in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to programing and am currently messing around trying to make a bot that will add items to my cart for me. I am using python with the selenium module. The problem I have came across is getting the program to find find an item using with src or href code.

```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(())
  )
  element.click()
```

This is the code I am using and I dont know what to put in the brackets to find the src or href. I am wondering which one is easier to use and how to use it in my code. Any advice/criticism at all could help me as I am still learning python. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Sweetjay, do you have more code you could share besides the one line? Also it would help if you had an example site with an example web element you are trying to access. That way we have more to base our response off of!

Comment: an example of the href is : https://'website'/shop/jackets/sawlq1dz6/mewsmibh3   I am getting to the page fine by using that same code and searching By.LINK_TEXT I just cant get my program to click on the item using the href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question is as follows:

> [How] to find find an item using with src or href code[?]

Let's take a code snippet as an example.
[image]

This is from the https://www.google.com/ startpage. If you want to find this `anchor` element with said `href` attribute by specifically looking for the href url, you need to search with e.g.:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=rm&amp;ogb"]')
```

---

Same goes for your code snippet:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('//a[@href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=rm&amp;ogb"]'))))
element.click()
```

---

Imported modules:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```